# Multiple Queries with meta_query

Tags: meta-query

I am trying to list posts in category 'Featured1314' split into two lists, upcoming events are >= todays date, past events are < todays date. I have added custom fields to the posts with the name of 'concert_date' and the values match the date format Ymd (ex: 20140611)

The code I am using below is close, the first query has the correct results, but the second query results are duplicates of the first query.

```
<h1>2013-14 Concert Season</h1>
        <?php
            $today = date('Ymd');
            $args1 = array(
                'type' => 'post',
                'category_slug' => 'Featured1314',
                'meta_key' => 'concert_date',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'concert_date',
                            'value' => $today,
                            'compare' => '>='
                        )
                    ),
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => 'ASC'
                );
            $upcoming_query = new WP_Query($args1); 
            if( $upcoming_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <h2>Upcoming Concerts</h2>
        <ul><?php while ( $upcoming_query->have_posts() ) { $upcoming_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1><p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p></li>
        <?php } }?>
        </ul>
        <?php 
            rewind_posts();
            $today = date('Ymd');
            $args2 = array(
                'type' => 'post',
                'category_slug' => 'Featured1314',
                'meta_key' => 'concert_date',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'concert_date',
                            'value' => $today,
                            'compare' => '<'
                        )
                    ),
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => 'ASC'
                );
            $past_query = new WP_Query($args2); 
            if( $past_query->have_posts() ) {?>
            <h2>Past Concerts</h2>
        <ul><?php while ( $past_query->have_posts() ) { $past_query->next_post(); ?>
            <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1><p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p></li>
        <?php } }?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: I would remove the `rewind_posts()` after your first loop and replace it with a `wp_reset_postdata()`. `rewind_posts()` will go back to the first post in the previous query (being the `$upcoming_query` where `wp_reset_postdata()` will revert back to the original WP_Query Object where you can then overwrite it with your `$past_query`. I would also cut down on some code and put `$today` at the very top since it will have the same value in both queries versus calling `date()` twice.

Comment: I have tried wp_reset_postdata() and the results are that the second query lists the home page multiple times.

Comment: I've turned my comment into an answer since it seemed helpful which if it solved your problem you can click the checkmark so everybody else knows the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this which is mostly code clean up but may solve your problem. I removed the `relation` from `meta_query` as it's only needed if you have multiple meta keys in your query, which you don't. I've also replaced the `rewind_posts()` with `wp_reset_postdata()` and finally, you were ending your `IF` statements earlier than your `UL` tags, which if it is false you'll have orphan `</ul>`'s hanging around which is never good.

```
<h1>2013-14 Concert Season</h1>
    <?php
        $today = date('Ymd');

        $args1 = array(
            'type' => 'post',
            'category_slug' => 'Featured1314',
            'meta_key' => 'concert_date',
            'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'concert_date',
                        'value' => $today,
                        'compare' => '>='
                    )
                ),
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'ASC'
            );
        $upcoming_query = new WP_Query($args1); 

        if( $upcoming_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
            <h2>Upcoming Concerts</h2>
            <ul><?php while ( $upcoming_query->have_posts() ) { $upcoming_query->the_post(); ?>
                <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1><p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p></li>
            <?php } // endwhile ?>
            </ul>
        <?php } // endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();
        $args2 = array(
            'type' => 'post',
            'category_slug' => 'Featured1314',
            'meta_key' => 'concert_date',
            'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'concert_date',
                        'value' => $today,
                        'compare' => '<'
                    )
                ),
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );
        $past_query = new WP_Query($args2); 
        if( $past_query->have_posts() ) {?>
            <h2>Past Concerts</h2>
            <ul><?php while ( $past_query->have_posts() ) { $past_query->the_post(); ?>
                <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1><p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p></li>
            <?php } //endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php } // endif;
```